# What weight and balance form should I use for my checkride?

Tags: weight-and-balance, student-pilot, checkride

I am studying for private pilot checkride and saw this form in an Oral Exam. Can you tell me where I can get this form online? If not, is there a better form for expiration and W&B data?

[image: Expiration and WB form]

Comment: There's no standard form for this information, if that's what you're asking. Pilots usually make their own W&B forms, get one from their instructor, or copy them from the POH. The inspection dates are just a list, there's nothing special there and the aircraft owner will usually have a list somewhere already. The simplest thing is probably to make your own sheet and go over it with your instructor, to make sure you have all the relevant information.

Comment: FWIW, if you Google "online weight and balance" you'll find several programs for various aircraft.

Comment: Thanks for your input. Issue/Expiration part is easy to make. For the planes I use, there are excel worksheets where we only need to know weights and gas information to get outputs. I will make/find a printed version of that.

Comment: @ferviate83 just to reiterate an important point: make sure those worksheets are specific to *that particular* airplane, and not merely generic.  it is unlikely that two airplanes of the same model will have the exact same weight data from "the shop" that is needed to be legally correct.

Answer (score 4):

Use the same form you use every other time you go fly with your instructor.

If you're at the point of preparing for a check-ride and you have never had a weight and balance form before, you may want to sue your flight instructor (...kidding, kind of).

If I approach a new trainer-airplane for the first time, I find out whether someone has made a weight and balance form for the plane yet and ask for a copy.  If not, one can be created using the data in the AFM in Excel or other spreadsheet program.

I like to make mine fully-automated as much as possible for day-to-day usage, but they can still be filled in manually for the purpose of demonstrating the understanding to an examiner.

If you use LibreOffice Calc, you can download [the one I made for the plane I use](http://www.mortensenaviation.com/files/N6285FDataSheet.ods).

[image: The spreadhseet]

[image]

If you try to open it with other software, it will look screwed up, but you can still get the idea.

The light blue shaded fields are the only ones that can have data entered into them.  The graph is created based on the weight data, and it automatically subtracts the fuel burn based on the flight duration.  So the two connected dots are the takeoff and landing C.G./Weight combinations.

This was all done from scratch using the AFM's data.  It takes some work, but it is worth it.  Your instructor *should* have something like this made already.

Comment: Doesn't LibreOffice have an option to export to . pdf?

Comment: @TomMcW It does indeed.  I was planning on adding a screenshot since it wouldn't have to be hosted.

Answer (score 2):

As [Pondlife](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/users/62/pondlife) mentions in the comments there is no officially accepted form per say but you must insure that the values you use to calculate WB are out of the POH for *THE SPECIFIC* aircraft you are flying that day. For your checkride you will be required to bring along all the paperwork for the plane which includes the POH. Since a given airframe may have small alterations like avionics variations or other modifications that effect empty weight and CG and the such the numbers from plane to plane may differ.

Some POH's may have example worksheets like [this one for the Piper Warrior (see page 6-11)](http://www.wrongbrosftw.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/Warrior-PA28-161-POH.pdf).

[image]

No matter the worksheet you use you should check the published procedure for calculating WB in the specific POH. Granted most of the procedures will be the same you should follow them none the less (you may be asked about how you arrived at a given value). My flight school had a form, I was comfortable with it so thats the one I used.

[image]

The video you linked (which I also watched many times before my check ride) is a bit dated but still relevant. You should note that the dates he is pointing to on that form are taken out of the log books. Your DPE may (mine did) ask you to show him the date in the actual logs that quick reference is not an official document. You should go over the POH and logs of the aircraft before your checkride to make sure that everything is in line and up to date. Strictly speaking you can bust your check ride if you show up in an aircraft that is not airworthy.

*Real Wold Scenario:* Every DPE varies the oral exam a bit so here is the WB stuff I had to answer. Before I even got there my DPE gave me his weight and had me to the WB for our XC flight (full fuel). He went over the numbers when I got there, I had the luxury of checking that a few times before showing up. After that he created a scenario for me (flights with friends etc). Had me run some WB to make sure we could make it, take off performance as well. He also asked me some questions about moving stuff around in the plane to shift CG if I needed to, as well as the effects of a far aft and far forward CG on the flight characteristics of the plane.